# What are values relative to Hask?

Tags: ct.category-theory, haskell, monad

According to ncatlab's page on category theory and haskell, 
"*we can identify a subset of Haskell called Hask that is often used to identify concepts used in basic category theory. One considers Haskell types as objects of a category whose morphisms are extensionally identified Haskell functions.*"

So types are objects, and functions are morphisms.  How, then, does a value, such as the list [1,2,3] or the boolean "true", fit into a category-theoretic definition of Haskell?  (I realize that lists, as monads, are presumably different in any category theoretical representation than booleans, which could be described as a coproduct, but I don't understand how the actual values in either case are related to the definition of Hask).

Comment: See this stack overflow post https://stackoverflow.com/q/17380379/6511076

Comment: also worth reading: http://blog.sigfpe.com/2009/10/what-category-do-haskell-types-and.html

Comment: This is not [the category you are looking for](http://math.andrej.com/2016/08/06/hask-is-not-a-category/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the level of precision used in the nlab page, values are [*global elements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_element) -- i.e., a value of type $A$ corresponds to a morphism $1 \to A$.

If you want to be serious about this, there are some technicalities to account for:

1. First, actual Haskell does not actually form a category in the sense that we would hope -- the `seq` operator breaks a lot of the program equivalences we need. However, if it were removed, then the pure fragment of Haskell would form a category (basically corresponding to the category of domains and continuous functions).
2. However, global elements in "Hask" (how I hate this terminology!) are not precisely values, since the nonterminating computation is an inhabitant of every type, and so for every type $A$ there is a map $\mathsf{loop}_A : 1 \to A$ which just runs forever.

   If you want to distinguish between values and nonterminating computations, then you need a somewhat more complicated setup, corresponding to the models of Paul Blain Levy's [*call-by-push-value*](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~pbl/papers/hosc05.pdf).

   There, you work with two categories -- one, a category of values, and the other, a category of computations, with an adjunction which gives you two functors, one embedding values into computations and the other embedding computations into values.

Comment: Are you lamenting about "Hask" or about "global element"? Global element makes perfect sense, if you think about programs geometrically.

Comment: Hask. I find it very twee.

Comment: Hasky would be worse.